# How can I read the data in firebase with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I tried some things but I cant read the data. I'm a beginner in flutter and I have to do a project that it shows the data in firebase. Can you show a beginner project that it only shows the datas in direbase?

I tried this too but this code have some errors on await (how it's possible I copied this from flutter official site)

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("users/123");
// Get the data once
DatabaseEvent event = await ref.once();
// Print the data of the snapshot
print(event.snapshot.value);
```

Thanks for replys I checked the await keyword and correct them (I think)
But I dont know how to print this
Can you show me that too
And I edited code to this =>

```
Future<Object?> GetData() async {
  FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("litre");

// Get the data once
  DatabaseEvent event = await ref.once();

// Print the data of the snapshot
  print(event.snapshot.value); // { "name": "John" }
  return event.snapshot.value;
}
```

Comment: This is so important project for me. I'm 10th grade

Comment: You can use the `await` keyword to wait for the result of a `future` and on an `async` method, did you use it in the correct place? please check this link : https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: please edit your question to include the error you're getting.

Comment: @mahmoud_eslami  how can i print the return value of this method using Text() function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you're calling the GetData method you need to await it...or if it is a widget which needs to display data after fetching it from firebase you can wrap it with a future builder.

I hope this solves your problem, if it still doesn't, post with the specific error you're getting.

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: GetData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else {
        if (snapshot.error != null) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('An error occured'),
          );
        } else {
          return Text(snapshot.data); // Or whatever widget you want to return or display
        }
      }
    },
  ),
```